# Device not ready, Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak]

Tags: 14.04, drivers, intel-wireless, iwlwifi

Am using Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak], in HP Probook 6560b. I am receiving an error that "device not ready" on Ubuntu 14.04, I have tried different OS's but all state the same thing. I then compiled kernels 3.16, 4.1.5, and now 4.3.6. All show the same things. I have installed the drivers iwlwifi-6000g2a-ucode in */lib/firmware/* but not help. Also, in all forums I have visited there is not a solution that works for me. Please help !

```
$ dmesg | grep iwl
[   48.595771] iwlwifi 0000:24:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[   48.596011] iwlwifi 0000:24:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[   48.596110] iwlwifi 0000:24:00.0: Radio type=0x1-0x0-0x1
[   49.602152] iwlwifi 0000:24:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
[   49.602160] iwlwifi 0000:24:00.0: Unable to initialize device.
[   49.602320] iwlwifi 0000:24:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[   49.602564] iwlwifi 0000:24:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
```

---

```
$ lscpi -nnk | grep -iA2 net
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82579V Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1503] (rev 04)
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:1619]
        Kernel driver in use: e1000e
24:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak] [8086:0085]
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 AGN [8086:1311]
        Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

---

```
$ rfkill list
0: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

---

```
$ dmesg | tail -25
[ 7321.282113] iwlwifi 0000:24:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
[ 7321.282124] iwlwifi 0000:24:00.0: Unable to initialize device.
[ 7321.284095] iwlwifi 0000:24:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[ 7321.284372] iwlwifi 0000:24:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[ 7321.284474] iwlwifi 0000:24:00.0: Radio type=0x1-0x0-0x1
[ 7322.293645] iwlwifi 0000:24:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
[ 7322.293657] iwlwifi 0000:24:00.0: Unable to initialize device.
[ 7322.294107] iwlwifi 0000:24:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[ 7322.294353] iwlwifi 0000:24:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[ 7322.294451] iwlwifi 0000:24:00.0: Radio type=0x1-0x0-0x1
[ 7323.301183] iwlwifi 0000:24:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
[ 7323.301266] iwlwifi 0000:24:00.0: Unable to initialize device.
[ 7323.303038] iwlwifi 0000:24:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[ 7323.303362] iwlwifi 0000:24:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[ 7323.303469] iwlwifi 0000:24:00.0: Radio type=0x1-0x0-0x1
[ 7324.312613] iwlwifi 0000:24:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
[ 7324.312623] iwlwifi 0000:24:00.0: Unable to initialize device.
[ 7324.313008] iwlwifi 0000:24:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[ 7324.313240] iwlwifi 0000:24:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[ 7324.313337] iwlwifi 0000:24:00.0: Radio type=0x1-0x0-0x1
[ 7325.320128] iwlwifi 0000:24:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
[ 7325.320147] iwlwifi 0000:24:00.0: Unable to initialize device.
[ 7325.324200] iwlwifi 0000:24:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[ 7325.324483] iwlwifi 0000:24:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[ 7325.324587] iwlwifi 0000:24:00.0: Radio type=0x1-0x0-0x1
```

Comment: Please edit the question to add the results from terminal for `dmesg | grep iwl`

Comment: No output at all?  Edit question to include `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net`

Comment: Am really new to this!

Comment: What happens when you `sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi && sleep 20 && sudo modprobe iwlwifi`

Comment: modprobe: FATAL: Module iwlwifi is in use.      That is the only output i got.

Comment: Post `cat /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf`  See what happens with `sudo modprobe -r iwldvm && sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi && sleep 20 && sudo modprobe iwldvm && sudo modprobe iwlwifi` Then wait 20 seconds and edit the question to include `dmesg | tail -25`

Comment: It may be broke

Comment: I don't think it is broken, bcoz on kernel `3.16` using ndiswrapper. It work well but there are a few limitations since ndiswrapper is not available for any kernel `3.16.+`. Also i don't get the full range of the connections that  the card is able to connect to i.e 802.11 a/b/g/n. Only 802.11 b/g are visible